# what is the best practice to send data to client android application

Tags: android

what is the best practice to send data to client android application using web-server or Google cloud management or web services . i want to send SVGfile to android client application from my pc or my server.

Comment: This question is subjective. The question might get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending data to the client (which assumes your client becomes a server somehow listening to that kind of data) I would just trigger an event on the client which will then download the data from the server.

So let's assume these two options:

1. your client queries your webserver every X minutes to see if there is something (new) to download
2. you receive a push message via Google cloud 2 device message system

Both will then trigger a download routine. Here is an example how to download an image via URL [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

To send data in this direction (from PC to Android), you need Google Cloud Messaging:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

because the app in client may be "sleeping"